# I can't get buttons to align correctly for different devices in the Storyboard Editor

Tags: storyboard, uistackview

I've tried a thousand different things, wasting days never getting it right. I'm attempting to use a UIStackView to hopefully relieve all these problems, but nope, the Storyboard Editor still proves itself to be horribly designed and broken.

My main concern are the buttons down at the bottom being viewed on an iPhone 8 Plus. I'd like them evenly spaced for any device, but I haven't figured that out without them going outside the bounds of other phones. They are in a UIStackView.

[image: story board view]

My Size Inspector for the UIStackView with constraints:

[image: UIStackView Size Inspector with Constraints]

Running this on my device (iPhone 6s Plus) does not look like this at all. The buttons do not show up. Somehow it messed up my UIPickerView to show like it is there which I had customized programmatically to scroll sideways which is now somehow being ignored. I hope I have enough undo levels to get it back to at least where it used to be.

All I want in the end is the bottom horizontally placed buttons to be placed evenly there, with even spacing on every device. How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of stack view you can use just UIView with clear colour  to adjust your constraints. Just like this

[image]

Preview in 8+ , 8 , SE

[image]

Comment: I wish I could even start doing this, but when I add a UIView, it the leading and trailing space options are grayed out. I tried adding constraints to the UIView, and they still don't show up, therefore I can't even get the UIView's width to match the device.

Comment: I can't even find that equal widths constraint

Comment: Equal value constrains only active if you select 2 or more view

Comment: I've selected all the buttons. I've also selected the view and all the buttons. Nothing.

Comment: Try > right click drag from your one button (button 1) to super view and release. A pop with equal width will be shown and Select the constrain and change multiplier. Then repeat it from button 2 to button 1 , in this do not change multiplier

Comment: I selected equal width, but that stretches the graphic for that one button. If I have all buttons selected and do that, it does the same thing to that one button.

Comment: I can't even do one button at a time because it moves the others over so much I can no longer see them from the other one stretching horizontally.

Comment: I cannot seem to get my views aligned in the same way. I can't even get constraints until I drag in a certain button. Setting equal width does not conform correctly between other device sizes. See my storyboard if you wish: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=31695799362873061753

Comment: I wonder how wrong it would be for me just to try to do it programmatically

Comment: Thanks, hey I'm just going to mark this question as correct. I'm having so much better luck doing this programmatically.